# How do I convert this Java code from using TreeMap to TreeMultiMap?

Tags: java, guava, treemap, generic-collections

I have a method thats returns a widget with the highest value for an attribute call source, this works fine except when there are multiple widgets with the same
    highest value for source, in this case it only returns the last widget added

```
private Widget getWidgetWithMostSources(List<Widget> Widgets)
{
    SortedMap<Integer,Widget> mapOfWidgetsSortedBySources = new TreeMap<Integer, Widget>();
    for(Widget next:Widgets)
    {
        mapOfWidgetsSortedBySources.put(next.getSources().intValue(), next);
    }
    //Just return the Widget with the highest source value
    Widget Widget = mapOfWidgetsSortedBySources.get(mapOfWidgetsSortedBySources.lastKey());
    return Widget;
}
```

So im trying to use Google Guavas TreemultiMap instead but I am having two problems,

1. It doesnt like the generic variables declared when I contruct the TreeMultiMap. **Update** I think it is because Widget does not implement comparable but I cannot modify the Widget class this is provided by a third party. I only need sorted key and multivalues for keys, I dont need sorted values so perhaps there is another class I could use ?
2. there is no lastKey() method, so how can I fix this:

Code:

```
private List<Widget> getWidgetWithMostSources(List<Widget> Widgets) {
    List<Widget> filteredWidgets = new ArrayList<Widget>();
    TreeMultimap<Integer, Widget> mapOfWidgetsSortedBySources = TreeMultimap.create();
    for (Widget next : Widgets) {
        mapOfWidgetsSortedBySources.put(next.getSources().intValue(), next);
    }
    //Just return the Widget with the highest source linked to the acoustid
    Set<Widget> WidgetsWithHighestSources = mapOfWidgetsSortedBySources.get(mapOfWidgetsSortedBySources.keys().lastKey());
    filteredWidgets.addAll(WidgetsWithHighestSources);
    return filteredWidgets;
}
```

**Update**

This compiles and I think is okay for what I want:

```
TreeMultimap<Integer, Recording> mapOfRecordingsSortedBySources = TreeMultimap.create(Ordering.natural(), Ordering.arbitrary());
```

Comment: I didnt understand first of your problem. Can you rephrase?

Comment: @talex it doesnt like this line TreeMultimap<Integer, Widget> mapOfRecordingsSortedBySources = TreeMultimap.create() if I change to TreeMultimap<Integer, String> its okay, but thats no good for me

Comment: @talex i updated question with more details

Comment: I suggest you not to use `Ordering.arbitrary()` because it consume memory. Use `Ordering.allEqual()` instead.

Comment: And you can answer you own question. So instead putting answer in question press "Answer" button :)

Comment: I want sure if right, which it wasn't quite because I didnt use allEqual() thats why didnt add own answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem may be solved with `TreeMultimap<Integer, Widget> mapOfWidgetsSortedBySources = TreeMultimap.create(Ordering.natural(), Ordering.allEqual());`

To solve second use `asMap()` method to get `NavigableMap` and then call `lastKey()`

Or you can use `lastEntry` and save your time on `mapOfWidgetsSortedBySources.get` call.

In result we have

```
private List<Widget> getWidgetWithMostSources(List<Widget> widgets) {
    List<Widget> filteredWidgets = new ArrayList<Widget>();
    TreeMultimap<Integer, Widget> mapOfWidgetsSortedBySources = TreeMultimap.create(Ordering.natural(), Ordering.allEqual());
    for (Widget next : widgets) {
        mapOfWidgetsSortedBySources.put(next.getSources().intValue(), next);
    }
    //Just return the Widget with the highest source linked to the acoustid
    Collection<Widget> widgetsWithHighestSources = mapOfWidgetsSortedBySources.asMap().lastEntry().getValue();
    filteredWidgets.addAll(widgetsWithHighestSources);
    return filteredWidgets;
}
```

**WARNING** Use `Ordering.arbitrary()` instead of `Ordering.allEqual()`

Or better use `MultimapBuilder.treeKeys().arrayListValues().build()` instead of `TreeMultimap.create(Ordering.natural(), Ordering.allEqual());`

Comment: Thanks that fixes the second problem, but I cant see whats wrong with the initial declaration

Comment: By default they try to sort values for one key (Don't know why they do it).

Comment: @talex `allEqual()` will only allow one `Widget` per `Integer` key, because it doesn't allow duplicate values for a key, and _all_ values are duplicates according to `allEqual()`.  `arbitrary()` is definitely what you want; or `MultimapBuilder.treeKeys().arrayListValues().build()` if you don't actually want sorted values.

Comment: @LouisWasserman For some weird reason this this version of multy-map want to sort values for same key. I suggest to use `Ordering.natural()` for keys and `Ordering.allEqual()` for **values**.

Comment: @talex no, that is still wrong.  TreeMultimap will always sort and deduplicate values for the same key, that is how it works.  You don't want allEqual() anywhere.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I checked that and found that you right. It mean that it is impossible to use this implementation in this case because of only working alternative (`arbitrary()`) looks like a joke. It have hashmap inside to remember order. In this case I suggest to use some other implementation. In worst case (if all other implementation have same problem) you need to implement it yourself.

Comment: `arbitrary()` is not particularly a joke, but I already explained an alternate solution, `MultimapBuilder.treeKeys().arrayListValues().build()`.

Comment: Ok. Maybe it is my strange sense of humor. But I hardly can imagine use case when it can be used. `MultimapBuilder.treeKeys().arrayListValues().build()` is good solution. It doesn't use ordering of values and have simple `ArrayList` as container.

Comment: @talex okay I go back to arbitary() then since the order of the values doesnt matter to me.